# "New messages" count for Thunderbird on Taskbar

Tags: kubuntu, thunderbird, notifications, tray

I would like to see the "new messages" count number on my taskbar, like Google Mail, for example something like:

```
Inbox(2) - Mozilla Thunderbird
```

I found FireTray, but it doesn't quite work, the taskbar remains unchanged even when I have new messages:

[image]

Is it possible to have count number like GMail? I am using Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, Xenial with KDE and Thunderbird version 52.6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, ensure that indicator support is installed on your system (packages libindicator7 and libindicator3-7).

This will enable you system to **receive** indicator messages.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libindicator7 libindicator3-7
```

Then on Thunderbird open Tools → Add-ons. There ensure that the Extension named "Messaging Menu and Unity Launcher Integration" is enabled (it should be installed by default).

This will enable Thunderbird to **send** indicator messages to the system.

Finally restart Thunderbird.

This is how the badge icon appears in the default "Task Manager" (which is your case),

[image]

while this is how it appears switching to the "Task Manager Icon Only" applet.

[image]

In any case, note that the indicator does not count the number of **unread** messages, but the **new** messages instead (which is what you asked for). For example, here I have a lot of unread messages, but only 2 of them are new. That's why the counter indicator shows the number 2.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work for me for Kubuntu 18.04 LTS, KDE Plasma 5.12.7.

Answer (score 0):

`libindicator3-7` and `libindicator7` are already installed by default as well as "Messaging Menu and Unity Launcher Integration" add-on in Mozilla Thunderbird. So all steps provided in [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/438082/52745) were useless in my case.

I remember that I had messages' count badge displayed on my notebook with Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS installation. It uses GNOME as desktop environment by default. I installed `kubuntu-desktop` there and switched to KDE Plasma later. But in a fresh installation of Kubuntu 18.04.2 with KDE Plasma only a badge with messages' count is not shown.

[Following this fairly old thread](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=96743) I got it working by installing `thunderbird-gnome-support` package:

```bsh
sudo apt install thunderbird-gnome-support
```

Just restart Thunderbird after that.